# Why does ref returns 'undefined' at first but if it's inside a callback, it returns the referenced element?

Tags: vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div class="block" v-if="showBlock" @click="stopTimer" ref="blob">
    Click Me!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['delay'],
    data() {
        return {
            showBlock: false,
            timer: null,
            reactionTime: 0
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.showBlock = true
            this.changePosition()
        }, this.delay)
    },
    methods: {
        changePosition() {
            console.log(this.$refs.blob)
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(this.$refs.blob)
            }, 1);
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

The first `ref` returns `undefined` while the second one inside the `setTimeout` returns the referenced element. I don't believe this is simply because the element hasn't been mounted yet. 1 millisecond cannot possibly make a difference. So, why is the referenced element `undefined` when the function is first invoked, but if I use a `setTimeout`, then it works?

Comment: Because v-if and v-for work in their own way and aren't guaranteed to be applied instantly, you can be pretty sure that they aren't. This is the case for nextTick

Comment: @EstusFlask So you are saying the 1 millisecond makes a difference?

Comment: Setting `showBlock` to true will update the element when it is rendered, not at that exact line of code. Using `setTimeout` delays execution of your code and happens to be when the item updated to a valid reference. As Estus Flask wrote, using `nextTick` makes sure the element has been updated.

Comment: It's not necessarily 1ms. It's about when the changes from v-if are applied. In this case nextTick could be synchronous (currently it's async and based on promises so it's generally faster than 1ms), but this wouldn't affect how it works - the framework renderer applies these changes after it calls mounted callbacks but before it calls nextTick callbacks